# Bootstrap datetimepicker fires dp.change when opening calendar

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the bootstrap datetimepicker and I noticed that the 'dp.change' event is fired when I open the calendar for the first time and it displays the date of today which is default selected date. I want to avoid that and fire the event once I choose the date on the calendar. Is that possible?

To initialize my datetimepicker, I'm using the following code:

```
$('#myDatepicker2').datetimepicker({ format:'YYYY-MM-DD'});
```

To catch the date once changed:

```
$('#myDatepicker2').on('dp.change', function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This was my issue

If you have set a default value like below

```
$('#dtpYearText').val(new Date().getFullYear());
```

change it like below

```
$('#dtpYear').data('DateTimePicker').date(moment(new Date()).format('YYYY'));
```